# Blazor wasm how to handle number formating if cultureinfo isnt valid for html

Tags: localization, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a pretty specific problem in my blazor app.

In my app I support multiple languages. For now thats english and  german.

Where the issue is coming in is if I do something like this:

```
<div class="bar-container" style="width: @(barWidth)px; height: @(barHeigth)px;">
    <div class="bar" style="">
        <div class="bar-text">Some Text</div>
    </div>
</div>

@code
{
    double barWidth = 120.5;
    double barHeigth = 20;
}
```

For this code, if I run it with the english cultureinfo everything works fine as it renders to

```
<div class="bar-container" style="width: 120.5px; height: 20px;">
    <div class="bar" style="">
        <div class="bar-text">Some Text</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But in the case of german the result is

```
<div class="bar-container" style="width: 120,5px; height: 20px;">
    <div class="bar" style="">
        <div class="bar-text">Some Text</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is because in german the decimal point is a comma. Now html does have an issue interpreting 120,5px and returns weird results.

What is the best way to handle this?

Some ideas I have are:

- Setting the coltureinfo to english in the setup and handling localization another way
- Adding the english cultureinfo everytime I use a .ToString
- Always rounding to the next Int

Comment: Always specify the culture when parsing data is good practice.

Comment: When parsing data, you can use the [Invariant Culture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture).